# Running an Asyncio loop within a time interval

Tags: python, python-asyncio

**Goal**: run `main()` consisting of a bunch of asyncio functions between `start_time` and `end_time`

```
import datetime as dt

start_time, end_time= dt.time(9, 29), dt.time(16, 20)
```

`current_time()` just keeps adding the current time to work space. This time is used at several different points in the script not shown here

```
async def current_time(): 
    while True:
        globals()['now'] = dt.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
        await asyncio.sleep(.001)
```

Another function that does something:

```
async def balance_check():
    while True:    
        #do something here
        await asyncio.sleep(.001)
```

`main()` awaits the previous coroutines:

```
async def main():
    while True:
#Issue:This is my issue. I am trying to make these
#coroutines only run between start_time and end_time. 
#Outside this interval, I want the loop to 
#shut down and for the script to stop.
        if start_time < now.time() < end_time : 

            await asyncio.wait([
                    current_time(),
                    balance_check(),
                    ])
        else:
            print('loop stopped since {} is outside {} and {}'.format(now, start_time, end_time))
            loop.stop() 


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

***Issue***: this keeps working even after end_time

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem with the code you’ve shown?

Comment: @mkrieger1 edited

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but I am trying to understand _why_ you would want to do this. All I can think is you either (1) want to run one function before or another that is being called from elsewhere, (2) you want to run functions at specific times, or (3) you are doing this for practice sake? I'm unsure. Could you specify that?

Comment: Do you have to use asyncio?

Comment: @FelipeFaria in this script, I am running a bunch of functions/coroutines concurrently using Asyncio and the loop. But I wish this entire script to run only between start_time and end_time.

Comment: @MAO3J1m0Op yes

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, I just don't understand the why -- but that's fine. See the answer below.

Comment: @FelipeFaria thanks for your answer. Also, what is a better way to run such a script with asyncio coroutines only between specific times in the day? Sounds like you would do this in an entirely different way

Comment: I suppose it depends. It makes sense to me if you have a larger `asyncio` environment and you want to run a function between some time range with access to the environment's memory stack. Otherwise, if it's just a simple `asyncio` task that must ran during some point in the day until another, I think it would be more practical to schedule a `cron-job` to call some synchronous function that will loop and create an `asyncio` loop every iteration and execute said asynchronous function until `time_end`. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @FelipeFaria makes sense. But I have no experience with cron so I am trying to keep everything including the scheduling part within this single script and Asyncio

Comment: Sometimes learning how to make a circle roll is easier than trying to _create_ a square that will roll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is incorrect use of `await asyncio.wait([current_time(), balance_check(),])`.

Awaiting `asyncio.wait()` waits for the specified awaitables to *complete*, i.e. either return a value or raise an exception. Since neither `current_time` nor `balance_check` ever return out of their infinite loops, the execution of `main()` never gets passed `await asyncio.wait(...)`, as this expression waits for both to finish. In turn, the `while` loop in `main()` never gets to its second iteration, and `loop.stop()` has no chance to run.

If the code's intention was to use `asyncio.wait()` to give coroutines a chance to run, `asyncio.wait` is not the tool for that. Instead, one can just start the two tasks by calling `asyncio.create_task()`, and then *do nothing*. As long as the event loop can run (i.e. it's not blocked with a call to `time.sleep()` or similar), asyncio will automatically switch between the coroutines, in this case `current_time` and `balanced_check` at their ~1-millisecond pace. Of course, you will want to regain control by the `end_time` deadline, so "doing nothing" is best expressed as a single call to `asyncio.sleep()`:

```
async def main():
    t1 = asyncio.create_task(current_time())
    t2 = asyncio.create_task(balance_check())
    end = dt.datetime.combine(dt.date.today(), end_time)
    now = dt.datetime.now()
    await asyncio.sleep((end - now).total_seconds())
    print('loop stopped since {} is outside {} and {}'.format(now, start_time, end_time))
    t1.cancel()
    t2.cancel()
```

Note that an explicit `loop.stop()` is not even necessary, because `run_until_complete()` will automatically stop the loop once the given coroutine completes. Calling `cancel()` on the tasks has no practical effect because the loop stops pretty much immediately; it is included to make those tasks complete, so that the garbage collector doesn't warn about destroying tasks that are pending.

As noted in the comments, this code doesn't wait for `start_time`, but that functionality is easily accomplished by adding another sleep before spawning the tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying answer. To be able to use `asyncio.create_task` I had to upgrade to Python > 3.7. Now, when I use your `main()` instead of mine, I get `RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running.` When I get rid of the whole loop object (last 6 lines of my code above) and instead use `asyncio.run(main())`, I get `RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop` Any ideas?

Comment: The code above doesn't work, unfortunately. With `asyncio.create_task()` you create a [Task object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) that must be awaitable. In other words, somewhere in your code before `t1.cancel(); t2.cancel()` you must call the coroutines `await t1; await t2` for `t1` and `t2` to execute.

Comment: Which if you call them with `await t1; await t2` you won't be looping them -- only calling the functions once for the entirety of the program. Say, however, you add `while True:` in the `current_time()` and `balance_check()` functions... now then, `t1.cancel(); t2.cancel()` never gets reached because of the `while True`, which never ends, therefore you never go back to `await t1; await t2;`.

Comment: @FelipeFaria Your comment is incorrect - unlike coroutine objects, tasks **do not** have to be awaited to execute, they are automatically executed by the event loop "in the background". If you don't believe, you can simply *run* the code from the answer and notice that it works.

Comment: @Saeed You can replace `asyncio.create_task()` with `loop.create_task()` in Python < 3.7. However, I don't understand why you would get such an exception - I tested the code on Python 3.7, and it works both with or without `asyncio.run`. [Full code here.](https://pastebin.com/SNeNsVWx)

Comment: @user4815162342 You are right, my apologies -- got myself confused for a second. However, note that while this runs the code from `now` to `end`, it won't run code between a `start` to `end.` However, I can see a few modifications making it work.  Good share for the OP. Excuse my misunderstanding.

Comment: No problem, now I just wish I could get rid of the downvote. :) Regarding waiting for `start`, that's straightforward to achieve just by adding a sleep *before* spawning the tasks.

Comment: Will be honest, my downvote is locked unless the post has a small edit. If you would be so kind, I'll return the vote :)

Comment: @FelipeFaria Did the edit (with information about waiting for start_time), thanks for the frankness!

Comment: @user4815162342 Of course -- we ought to be honest out here. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [synchronizing primitives'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html) to do this, specifically `events`.

```py
import datetime as dt
import asyncio

async def function(start_event, end_event):
    # Waits until we get the start event command.
    await start_event.wait()

    # Run our function until we get the end_event being set to true.
    index = 0
    while not end_event.is_set():
        print(f"Function running; index {index}.")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        index += 1

async def controller(start_event, end_event):
    # Will usually be this. Commented out for testing purposes. Can be passed by main.
    # Subtraction/addition does not work on dt.datetime(). Inequality does (> or <)
    # now, start, end = dt.datetime.now().time(), dt.time(17, 24), dt.time(18, 0, 30)

    now = dt.datetime.now()
    start, end = now + dt.timedelta(seconds=-10), now + dt.timedelta(seconds=10)

    # Starts our function.
    print(f"Starting at {start}. Ending in {end - now}. ")
    start_event.set()

    # Keeps checking until we pass the scheduled time.
    while start < now < end:
        print(f"Ending in {end - now}.")
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        now = dt.datetime.now()

    # Ends our function.
    end_event.set()
    print(f"Function ended at {now}.")

async def main():
    # Creates two indepedent events.
    # start_event is flagged when controller is ready for function to be ran (prevents misfires).
    # end_event is flagged when controller see's start < time.now < end (line 30).
    start_event = asyncio.Event()
    end_event = asyncio.Event()

    # Starts both functions at the same time.
    await asyncio.gather(
        controller(start_event, end_event), function(start_event, end_event)
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Starting our process.
    asyncio.run(main())
```

This method will require both `function` and `controller` to take up space in the `asyncio` loop. However, `function` will be locked for most of the time, and it will instead be the controller hogging loop resources with its `while` loop, so keep that in the back of your mind.